# Como puedo instalar pycrypto para machine?

Tags: python, pip

Eh intentado muchas cosas, es que quiero instalar la librería `machine` para programar un ESP32, intente pero sale error por que se ocupa primero instalar `pycrypto` para ello, intente con pip, con descargar la carpeta y ponerla en la carpeta de paquetes, también descargar Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0, también las herramientas que te da el visual studio bull tools, intente la de `pip install --upgrade setuptools,` busque informacion para pycrypto y resulta que ya no tiene soporte y que me ayudaría `pip pycryptodome`y `pip pycryptodomex`pero no ayuda. Encontre este enlace pero no le entiendo https://foroayuda.es/error-de-instalacion-de-microsoft-windows-python-3-6-pycrypto/. Ya no se que hacer. Si alguien me puede ayudar, le agradecería mucho.

```
C:\Users\Usuario>pip install machine
Collecting machine

  Using cached machine-0.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.2 kB)
Collecting pycrypto
  Using cached pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pycrypto, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pycrypto, machine
  Running setup.py install for pycrypto ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for pycrypto did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [183 lines of output]
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto
      copying lib\Crypto\pct_warnings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto
      copying lib\Crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\Hash\hashalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\Hash\HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\Hash\RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Hash
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Cipher
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\Util\asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\Util\Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\Util\number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\Util\py3compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\Util\randpool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\Util\RFC1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\Util\winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\Util\_number_new.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Util
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random
      copying lib\Crypto\Random\random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random
      copying lib\Crypto\Random\_UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random
      copying lib\Crypto\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
      copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
      copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
      copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
      copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
      copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\fallback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
      copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
      copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
      copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\rng_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
      copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\st_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_rfc1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_importKey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_rpoolcompat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test__UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_fallback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_generic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_nt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Protocol
      copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Protocol
      copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\Chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Protocol
      copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Protocol
      copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Protocol
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\PublicKey
      copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\PublicKey
      copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\PublicKey
      copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\PublicKey
      copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\PublicKey
      copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\PublicKey
      copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\PublicKey
      copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_slowmath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\PublicKey
      copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\PublicKey
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Signature
      copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_PSS.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Signature
      copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Signature
      copying lib\Crypto\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Signature
      Skipping optional fixer: buffer
      Skipping optional fixer: idioms
      Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
      Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
      running build_ext
      warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
      building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isrc/ -Isrc/inc-msvc/ -IC:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/winrand.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src/winrand.obj
      winrand.c
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(31): error C2061: error de sintaxis: identificador 'intmax_t'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(32): error C2061: error de sintaxis: identificador 'rem'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(32): error C2059: error de sintaxis: ';'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(33): error C2059: error de sintaxis: '}'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(35): error C2061: error de sintaxis: identificador 'imaxdiv_t'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(35): error C2059: error de sintaxis: ';'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(45): error C2143: error de sintaxis: falta '{' delante de '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2146: error de sintaxis: falta ')' delante del identificador '_Number'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2061: error de sintaxis: identificador '_Number'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2059: error de sintaxis: ';'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2059: error de sintaxis: ')'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(50): error C2143: error de sintaxis: falta '{' delante de '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2146: error de sintaxis: falta ')' delante del identificador '_Numerator'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2061: error de sintaxis: identificador '_Numerator'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2059: error de sintaxis: ';'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2059: error de sintaxis: ','
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(53): error C2059: error de sintaxis: ')'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(55): error C2143: error de sintaxis: falta '{' delante de '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(61): error C2143: error de sintaxis: falta '{' delante de '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(68): error C2143: error de sintaxis: falta '{' delante de '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(74): error C2143: error de sintaxis: falta '{' delante de '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(81): error C2143: error de sintaxis: falta '{' delante de '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(87): error C2143: error de sintaxis: falta '{' delante de '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(94): error C2143: error de sintaxis: falta '{' delante de '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(100): error C2143: error de sintaxis: falta '{' delante de '__cdecl'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pycrypto

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

C:\Users\Usuario>
```

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola! no sé si aun te ayude :"( pero acabo de tener la misma duda hoy y me parece que el modulo "machine" que intentas usar es el de MicroPython (dado que quieres programar un ESP32) y no el de  "pycryptodome", en el caso del MicroPython machine ya viene instalado según yo.

Referencia a MicroPython/machine:
https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.html